# Can't use token variable's method at contract that inherit zeppelin crowdsale?

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

Calling the method of Crowdsale's "token" on the source that inherited Crowdsale of zeppelin v1.8.0 inevitably causes "out of gas".

> Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: out of gas

Is it impossible to use token's method from crowdsale source on here?

## Environment

```
Truffle v4.1.5 (core: 4.1.5)
Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js)
zeppelin v1.8.0
EthereumJS TestRPC v4.0.1 (ganache-core: 1.0.1)
```

## Crowdsale Contract

Sample of zeppelin v1.8.0 is almost intact

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SimpleToken is StandardToken {

  string public constant name = "SimpleToken"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  string public constant symbol = "SIM"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18; // solium-disable-line uppercase

  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

  /**
   * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
   */
  function SimpleToken() public {
    totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
  }

}
```

--

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale, MintedCrowdsale {


  function SampleCrowdsale(
    uint256 _openingTime,
    uint256 _closingTime,
    uint256 _rate,
    address _wallet,
    uint256 _cap,
    MintableToken _token,
    uint256 _goal
  ) public
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)
  {
    //As goal needs to be met for a successful crowdsale
    //the value needs to less or equal than a cap which is limit for accepted funds
    require(_goal <= _cap);
  }

  function tokenTotalSupply()
      public
      constant
      returns (uint256)
  {
      return token.totalSupply();
  } 
}
```

After, deploy to testrpc, I got following error output...

```
truffle(testrpc)> mySale = SampleCrowdsale.at(SampleCrowdsale.address)
truffle(testrpc)> mySale.tokenToalSupply()
Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: out of gas
    at /c0ban-ico/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:59880:17
    at /c0ban-ico/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:88044:5
    :
    :
```

Comment: You typed `mySale.tokenToalSupply()` and your function is `mySale.tokenTotalSupply()`

Also, where is the variable `token` in the solidity code for  SampleCrowdsale defined, should be `_token`, no?

Comment: Oh,,, mySale.tokenToalSupply() was typo...

Comment: "token" is OK. Crowdsale.sol set "token" = "_token".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I changed from "ethereumjs-testrpc": "^4.0.1" to "ganache-cli": "^6.1.0".
It worked !